# Neo4j Cypher, START n=node(id) over MATCH id(n)=id

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I was wondering how

```
WHERE id(n) = id
```

compares to

```
START n = node(id)
```

as most of the time I do not select nodes by id (at least in number of code appearances) and therefore like to do it always in the match

Comment: In 2.0 `MATCH id(n) = id`  Should be: `MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = id`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The two statements are identical. `START` is the syntax to be used in Neo4j 1.x. From Neo4j 2.0 the `MATCH` variant should be preferred, maybe `START` will get deprecated at some future release.

Comment: Do you *know* that `START` is going to be deprecated or is this an assumption?

Comment: As long as long as legacy indexes are part of the product, `START` will stay. So expect it being there for a long time.

Comment: Right. I hope those eventually go as well :)

Comment: In 2.2 `START` will be only working for legacy indexes - for all other cases you have to use `MATCH`.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster It seems that 2.2 will allow START : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/3794

Answer (score -1):

MATCH (a:NodeName) where ID(a)= {id}  return ID(a), a.name ...////pass id //this is find by node id